# Format memory card with NTFS

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-system, external-sd

I have a Galaxy SIII and 32GB memory card. I want format the memory card with NTFS just to get rid of 4GB size per file restriction. How can I format the card with NTFS and even if I format it with NTFS will I be able to use it with Galaxy SIII?

Comment: Of course you can do that -- but it's very unlikely that your device can use it then. NTFS is a Windows file system format which is unlikely to be supported by Android devices (also check the [ntfs tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ntfs) here for details).

Comment: So how can I store files more than 4GB in external SD card?

Comment: Using e.g. [ext3](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ext3/info) -- but then you can no longer simply mount it to Windows without installing special software for it. I would rather think twice if "files bigger than 4GB" are really that important to you. // **BTW:** Your question clearly reflects a [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Your issue is "How to store files bigger than 4GB on my SDCard", not formatting the card with NTFS (that's what you think is the answer to your problem). You might want to rephrase it :)

Answer (score 6):

You can format the SD as exFAT, removing the 4Gb restriction from old FAT filesystem. You can format it from Windows (or Linux/Mac) without any third party application and the phone will recognize it without problems.

Comment: I was under the impression that exFat couldn't be read by Linux.

Answer (score -2):

NTFS can be read by linux, whereas exfat cannot be. the only problem is even and android is a linux flavor will it accept ntfs or not at it was a mobile os.